# Is it correct to add Stack Overflow activity as volunteering in Linkedin

Tags: discussion

I'm updating my LinkedIn profile and there is a place for "volunteering activity"

Is it correct to add Stack Overflow activity as volunteering in Linkedin?

As I see it, I expend a lot of time helping people for free and then it applies, but I don't want to break any rule, so I ask here.

EDIT
Well, There is an entry in Wikipedia about this.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_volunteering

Comment: Shouldn't you ask LinkedIn about that, not us?

Comment: It's in my "organisations"... don't suppose it matters one way or another.

Comment: You could argue that an analysis of whether answering questions on SO is in fact volunteering would both answer the question and be on-topic @Frédéric. There's  no real need to mention LinkedIn at all.

Comment: @Ben, no argument there in the general case, except our own definition of volunteering (or, more probably, the several different definitions we would provide) would have to apply to LinkedIn's own ideas about that.

Comment: Yeah I'd buy that ... we are not experts on jobs here. Curious also what career experts would think.

Comment: Have you been to [The Workplace Stack Exchange](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Hmm, could become awkward! Though, who cares on LinkedIN ;-P ...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm not a "career expert" but I do play one on TV.

Ok, I'll be serious now. I make hiring decisions. If someone mentions their participation to Stack Overflow (or any SE site, or any other site for that matter), that's good to know. I'll want to check how they act on the site, and depending on what I see the outcome could be a plus or a minus.

If someone lists their participation to Stack Overflow as "volunteering", that will earn a smirk from me. My immediate reaction is going to be that the person who describes their activity on SO as "volunteering" is really grasping at straws, unless they happen to be doing something which is **really out of the ordinary on SO**. Being a moderator, for instance, would qualify, because AFAIK moderators are pledging their time to the site. There's a certain formality to being a moderator that does not exist when someone just happens to be active on the site. (I don't always agree with the moderators, but hats off to the willingness to put up with the flow of crap that is thrown at SO on a daily basis.)

Also, the kind of activity matters. It is great if someone is active at answering questions. But as I see it, the selflessness that is often associated with volunteering is manifested more in those actions that do not give a direct benefit (i.e. reputation for the individual) like closing questions that need closing, participating in the review queues, editing, and flagging what needs flagging. So if for instance a candidate says they volunteer on SO and I go check their profile and find that in 3 years, they've got 5 reviews, 3 edits, and 9 flags, then they'll get a smirk first and a frown next, because that does not look like "volunteering" to me. (Yes, I know people can have an account on SO for years before they become "active". I've just chosen an easy example.)

But that's just me.

Comment: Offtopic: How do you see, how many reviews/edits a person has?

Comment: Go to that person's profile, click the "activity" tab. You'll see a series of buttons below the "activity" tab but above the list of activities. These allow to filter by type. The "revision" button will show only edits (revision == edit). The "reviews" button will show only reviews.

Comment: time is time, moderator or regular user, people use their time for others.

Comment: [number of helpful flags is public](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249988/165773) since Feb 2015. As an example, I can see that [your profile -> activity tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1906307/louis?tab=topactivity) currently shows 1331 flags (6 more to go to _leet_)

Comment: @ElzoValugi - But unlike regular users, moderators commit to spending a certain amount of time improving the site for others. Me spending a few minutes at random times to vote, comment, or flag is not the same thing as the diamond moderators essentially making up-keep of the site a part time job. It just isn't.

Comment: I disagree, regular users time spent on answers is equally important

Comment: I would say SO can be seen as volunteering, please see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_volunteering. "answering questions"  -is one of the bullet points there.

Answer (score 6):

I would say yes.
Volunteering is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volunteering) as:

> an altruistic activity where an individual ... provides services for no financial gain.

There are people who help with money, others help with their time and knowledge. I did spend time online doing translation of Ubuntu and I consider that volunteering. I did it to give back something to the community. I have the same feeling about helping people on SO. I learned so much from others and I see this as a way of giving back. The reward system of Stack overflow may be rewarding in some manner to one's ego, but let's be honest and recognize that those abstract points value little in the eyes of a recruiter, because they do not represent a comparable evaluation of your skills, but more of your time spent on the site. If you don't have a real wish of giving back, you won't spend so much time helping others on SO, you will just come when you need the answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is not conventional volunteering, because you're doing it *online*

And though we are, as a society, starting to be more virtual and internet-savvy, we are not yet at a point where the word "volunteering" is synonymous with StackOverflow.

Also, is it the same idea - to volunteer here VS. tutoring a 5-year old in an inner-city low-income school?

I just think it might not be entirely the right meaning that you're looking for.

At the end, your call...

Comment: I would say the online aspect contributes least to SO participation not being considered volunteering - it's certainly possibly to imagine doing similar volunteer work (mentoring/tutoring) online, but SO isn't that.

Answer (score -4):

I would say no.

"Volunteering" usually means spending time to help people "in need", often through some non-profit organization.

The main audience of SO is professional programmers doing their jobs. Providing answers to them would not match most people's definition of "volunteering". The fact that it's through the for-profit Stack Exchange, Inc. doesn't help.

Comment: Why not? Not all SO users are professional developers - most of them are amateurs/beginners - and helping them is volunteering IMO. e.g. Wiki: "Volunteering is generally considered an altruistic activity where an individual or group provides services for no financial gain.". There is even online volunteering mentioned on Wiki.

Comment: please check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_volunteering